# Sort groups in JSON file

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to collect some of the information out of this JSON page ('https://oa.ceair.com/common_source/airport/en_AU.json?v=1561031507803&_=1561031507712') and convert it into a text file on local harddrive.
More specifically, I only need strings that are on "match", "label" and "value".

```
import os, re, requests
def getCity():

  url='https://oa.ceair.com/common_source/airport/en_AU.json? 
       v=1561031507803&_=1561031507712'
  response=requests.get(url,verify=True)
  city=re.findall('([A-Z]+)',response.text)
  city=str(city)
  write(city)
```

Using the code above, the info has successfully inputted into another text file, however, it contains all the raw data.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's *json*, it's easy to work with. Requests has built-in support for it. Response's `json` method returns a `dict` which we can easily use:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(r"https://oa.ceair.com/common_source/airport/en_AU.json?v=1561031507803&_=1561031507712", verify=True)
airports = response.json()

with open(r"airport_info.txt", "wt") as f:
    for airport in airports:
        f.write(f"match: {airport['match']}\n") # Literal string interpolation
        f.write(f"label: {airport['label']}\n") # See https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/
        f.write(f"value: {airport['value']}\n")
```

airport_info.txt looks like this and goes for 1258 lines:

```
match: SYD,SYDNEY KINGSFORD SMITH APT,XiNiJinSiFuTe·ShiMiSiJiChang,XNJSFT·SMSJC
label: SYDNEY KINGSFORD SMITH APT, SYD
value: SYD
match: MEL,MELBOURNE,MoErBen,MEB
label: MELBOURNE, MEL
value: MEL
```

etc